# How can I publish external turnserver by using Nodeport via kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-pod

I don't have any knowledge about turnserver and trying to use turnserver by using Kubernetes from "zolochevska/turn-server"  image. (**My Linux is WSL2 - windows subsystem linux**)

**Deployment yaml: (turnserverdeployment.yml)**

```js
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: turn-server
  namespace: xxx-prod
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: turn-server
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: turn-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - yusuf
        - yusuf123
        - 176.55.12.108
        image: zolochevska/turn-server
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: turn-server
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
status:
  availableReplicas: 1
  observedGeneration: 5
  readyReplicas: 1
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

**and service yaml : (turnserverservice.yml)**

```js
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: turn-server
  name: turn-server
  namespace: xxx-prod
spec:
  ports:
  - name: tcp
    nodePort: 30100
    port: 3478
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 3478
  - name: udp
    nodePort: 30100
    port: 3478
    protocol: UDP
    targetPort: 3478
  selector:
    app: turn-server
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Localhost is working but WSL ip access is not working :

this my setup :

I tried to set externalip manuelly but it doesn't work for curl call :

```
kubectl patch svc turn-server -p '{"spec":{"externalIPs":["176.55.yyy.xxx"]}}'
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), while at it, also please don't post your public IP on the internet.